# Reactjs unexpected useState behaviour in slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I implemented autoplay Slider (having three cards) using useEffect, but manual "previous" and "forward" button are not working properly. useState is not upadating values as desired. useState is changing values that i am unable to understand that random behaviour. Once i clicked on previous or forward arrow to swipe slide than it started changing slides very quickly. Auto slider is working perfectly but i swipe manually than usestate changes value unexpectedly. how can i implement both auto and manual (forward and backward arrow) so that usestate changes value smoothly.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Card, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { SlideData, SliderImages } from "./SlideData";
import left from "../../../styles/img/homepg/AdmSlider/left.png";
import right from "../../../styles/img/homepg/AdmSlider/right.png";


function NewsSlider() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const firstRef = useRef(null);
  const secondRef = useRef(null);
  const thirdRef = useRef(null);
  const currentRef = useRef(null);


  const Left = () => {
    setFirst(first <= 0 ? len : first - 1);
    setSecond(second <= 0 ? len : second - 1);
    setThird(third <= 0 ? len : third - 1);
  };

  const Right = () => {
    setFirst(first >= len ? 0 : first + 1);
    setSecond(second >= len ? 0 : second + 1);
    setThird(third >= len ? 0 : third + 1);
  };

  const [first, setFirst] = useState(0);
  const [second, setSecond] = useState(1);
  const [third, setThird] = useState(2);

  const length = SliderImages.length;
  const len = length - 1;
  let timeout;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setFirst(first >= len ? 0 : first + 1);
      setSecond(second >= len ? 0 : second + 1);
      setThird(third >= len ? 0 : third + 1);
       return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
    }, 3000);
  }, [first, second, third]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Grid container xs={12} className={classes.grid}>
          {" "}
          <div>
            <img
              src={left}
              alt="leftarrow"
              className={classes.left}
              onClick={Left}
            />
          </div>
          <Grid item xs={4} className={classes.card}>
            {SliderImages.map((val, index) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  {index === first && (
                    <Card className={classes.card1}>
                      <img
                        src={val.imgsrc}
                        alt={val.title}
                        className={classes.image}
                        ref={firstRef}
                      />
                    </Card>
                  )}
                  {index === second && (
                    <Card className={classes.card2}>
                      <img
                        src={val.imgsrc}
                        alt={val.title}
                        className={classes.image}
                        ref={secondRef}
                      />
                    </Card>
                  )}
                  {index === third && (
                    <Card className={classes.card3}>
                      <img
                        src={val.imgsrc}
                        alt={val.title}
                        className={classes.image}
                        ref={thirdRef}
                      />
                    </Card>
                  )}
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src={right}
                      alt="rightarrow"
                      className={classes.right}
                      onClick={Right}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default NewsSlider;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Your issue is you start another timeout when you manually update one of `first`, `second`, or `third` without clearing any previous timeouts.

Also, `timeout` is redeclared each render cycle when you define it in the function body as `let timeout;`.

## Solution

Capture the timeout ref and return the clearing function from the `useEffect` callback instead of in the timeout callback.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    setFirst(first >= len ? 0 : first + 1);
    setSecond(second >= len ? 0 : second + 1);
    setThird(third >= len ? 0 : third + 1);
  }, 3000);

  return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
}, [first, second, third]);
```

## Alternative Solution

Construct the slider animation to be on an interval and use functional state updates to handle prev/next slides. The functional state updates allow you to use an interval timer and correctly update from the previous slide state while also allowing you to asynchronously manually slide left or right without interrupting the interval updates.

```
const Left = () => {
  setFirst(first => first <= 0 ? len : first - 1);
  setSecond(second => second <= 0 ? len : second - 1);
  setThird(third => third <= 0 ? len : third - 1);
};

const Right = () => {
  setFirst(first => first >= len ? 0 : first + 1);
  setSecond(second => second >= len ? 0 : second + 1);
  setThird(third => third >= len ? 0 : third + 1);
};

const [first, setFirst] = useState(0);
const [second, setSecond] = useState(1);
const [third, setThird] = useState(2);

const length = SliderImages.length || 0;
const len = length - 1;

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    Right();
  }, 3000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Comment: I got the answer, As you mentioned I was clearing the timeout `return () => clearTimeout(timeout);` at wrong position.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add arrow function in useState hook

```
  const Left = () => {
    setFirst(first => first <= 0 ? len : first - 1);
    setSecond(second => second <= 0 ? len : second - 1);
    setThird(third => third <= 0 ? len : third - 1);
  };

  const Right = () => {
    setFirst(first => first >= len ? 0 : first + 1);
    setSecond(second => second >= len ? 0 : second + 1);
    setThird(third => third >= len ? 0 : third + 1);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, but why we use callback function? as we already assigning the value to first second and third?